# SASS Compass - gradients compile, but create invalid CSS?

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I've tried the following:

```
@import 'compass';

.gradient {
    background-color: rgb(238,49,36); // Old browsers
    @include filter-gradient(#ee3124, #d12b20, vertical); // IE6-9
    @include background-image(linear-gradient(top,  rgba(238,49,36,1) 0%,rgba(209,43,32,1) 100%));
}
```

Which generates the following css:

```
.gradient {
  background-color: #ee3124;
  *zoom: 1;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FFEE3124', endColorstr='#FFD12B20');
  background-image: -owg(compact(linear-gradient(top, #ee3124 0%, #d12b20 100%), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
  background-image: -webkit(compact(linear-gradient(top, #ee3124 0%, #d12b20 100%), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
  background-image: -moz(compact(linear-gradient(top, #ee3124 0%, #d12b20 100%), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
  background-image: -o(compact(linear-gradient(top, #ee3124 0%, #d12b20 100%), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false));
  background-image: compact(linear-gradient(top, #ee3124 0%, #d12b20 100%), false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false, false);
}
```

Which **looks** like it's working, though the result is just "invalid property value" errors in Google Chrome, and just straight up ignored in FireFox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running the SASS plugin under NetBeans and it has its own Sass-watch like feature upon compile, so it is bypassing the compass watch feature. So SASS is generating SASS code within the css file, rather than compass generating CSS code.